# Regular expression for extracting Russian passport numbers

Tags: python, regex, string, data-extraction

I need regular extraction that extract passport number after specific word `паспорт` .

Possible options are:

- `паспорт 5715 424141`
- `паспорт 5715-424141`
- `паспорт 5715 - 424141`

I need to extract first 4 and last 6 numbers after word `паспорт` occurred, so result should be `5715` and `424141`.

I tried `^(\d{4})\ (\d{6})$` but it's not detected my pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, the `^` symbol means the start of the string, so that already fails your pattern (as the strings start with "паспорт").

It also seems that the `-` between the number groups is optional and may have spaces which you don't support.

To fix all those issues, use:

```
паспорт (\d{4})\s*-?\s*(\d{6})
```

- `паспорт`  - literal match.
- `(\d{4})` - a capture group of four digits.
- `\s*` - any number of spaces, including 0.
- `-?` - an optional dash.
- `\s*` - any number of spaces, including 0.
- `(\d{6})` - a capture group of six digits.

And since you tagged with Python:

```py
import re

s = """паспорт 5715 424141
паспорт 5715-424141
паспорт 5715 - 424141"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    print(re.search(r"паспорт (\d{4})\s*-?\s*(\d{6})", line).groups())
# ('5715', '424141')
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JGIjbX/1)